# Preferred approach for conditional compilation for 32-bit versus 64-bit versions of types 

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm required for a certain task to enumerate all handles in the system. The best approach I found so far is using the underdocumented [`NtQuerySystemInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `SystemHandleInformation` flag for the class parameter.

So far so good. However, running it in 32 bit mode on 64 bit Windows, the required structure is as follows:

```
// 32-bit version
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    public uint ProcessID;               
    public byte ObjectTypeNumber;       
    public byte Flags;                  
    public ushort Handle;               
    public uint Object_Pointer;       
    public UInt32 GrantedAccess;        
}
```

And for 64 bit Windows (x64, I didn't test Itanium, which I hope isn't different...), the structure is as follows:

```
// 64-bit version
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    public int Reserved;            // unknown, no documentation found
    public uint ProcessID;               
    public byte ObjectTypeNumber;       
    public byte Flags;                  
    public ushort Handle;               
    public long Object_Pointer;       
    public UInt32 GrantedAccess;        
}
```

Now, I should change the `Object_Pointer` to an `IntPtr`. I hoped for a moment I could do the same with `ProcessId`, there was a reference saying this was actually a `HANDLE` which is actually a 64-bit value. However, `Reserved` is always zero, so I cannot merge that into an `IntPtr` the same way.

This is probably not the only scenario where this happens. I'm looking for a best practice way of dealing with such differences:

- Using a constant like `#if WIN32` (used internally in the reference source of IntPtr) wouldn't work here unless I want to maintain separate binaries.
- I can write two different functions and two different structs, create a wrapper and use `if IntPtr.Size ==4` in code. This works for external functions, but doesn't work well with types.
- I can overload `GetType` but I'm not sure where that leads (might help with Marshalling?).
- Anything else?

None of these seem ideal, but so far, the only foolproof way seems to be to lard my system with `if IsWin64()` statements. I'd love to hear better approaches than mine.

Comment: This kind of code is like teenage sex, one mistake and you'll support it for the rest of your life.  Use the Process class to run SysInternals' Handle.exe utility, at least you can get somebody else to support that.

Comment: @HansPassant: LOL! Yes, I've considered using anyone of SysInternal's utilities, but no, doesn't fit my scenario. Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given IntPtr's size is different, why not try the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr ProcessID;               // mask with 0xffffffff
    public byte ObjectTypeNumber;       
    public byte Flags;                  
    public ushort Handle;               
    public IntPtr Object_Pointer;          // again good for 32/64bit
    public UInt32 GrantedAccess;        
}
```

This should work for both 32 and 64 bit unaltered.

Comment: Yes, I tried that a couple of times, but it yields the wrong ProcessID. Maybe it's a good idea, I should then expand the struct with a method `GetProcessId()` that does the unmasking and mark ProcessID private.

Comment: @Abel: In 64-bit, just rightshift 32 bits then. I was not sure about endian issues :)

Comment: It gets process ID 4 (system) as `0x0000000400000000`, which is `17179869184`, from the byte sequence `00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00`. So yes, endianness is an issue (in the sense that the leading reserved zeroes are in the way). `0x0000000400000000 >> 32` works in 64-bit cases.

Answer (score 3):

That's the thing - SystemHandleInformation's structures only give you 16-bit PIDs. You can use SystemExtendedHandleInformation on XP and higher.

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  public class SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX
  {
    public IntPtr Object;
    public IntPtr UniqueProcessId;
    public IntPtr HandleValue;
    public uint GrantedAccess;
    public ushort CreatorBackTraceIndex;
    public ushort ObjectTypeIndex;
    public uint HandleAttributes;
    public uint Reserved;
  }

  internal enum SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS
  {
    SystemBasicInformation = 0,
    SystemPerformanceInformation = 2,
    SystemTimeOfDayInformation = 3,
    SystemProcessInformation = 5,
    SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation = 8,
    SystemHandleInformation = 16,
    SystemInterruptInformation = 23,
    SystemExceptionInformation = 33,
    SystemRegistryQuotaInformation = 37,
    SystemLookasideInformation = 45,
    SystemExtendedHandleInformation = 64,
  }


 [DllImport("ntdll.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
 private static extern int NtQuerySystemInformation(int InfoType, IntPtr lpStructure, int StructSize, out int returnLength);



  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x32");
    Console.WriteLine();

    var infoSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX));

    Console.WriteLine("sizeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX): {0}", infoSize);
    int allSize = 1000 * infoSize;
    var buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(allSize);
    var status = NtQuerySystemInformation((int)SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS.SystemExtendedHandleInformation, buffer, allSize, out allSize);
    Console.WriteLine("status: {0:x}, return len: {1}", status, allSize);

    if (status != 0)
    {
      allSize += 40 * infoSize;
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
      buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(allSize);
      status = NtQuerySystemInformation((int)SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS.SystemExtendedHandleInformation, buffer, allSize, out allSize);
      Console.WriteLine("status: {0:x}, return len: {1}", status, allSize);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    var info = new SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX();
    //for (var i = 0; i < allSize; i += infoSize)
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.Min(allSize, 20 * infoSize); i+= infoSize) // for testing purpose only 20
    {
      Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr.Add(buffer, i), info);
      Console.WriteLine("{0,16:x}, {1,16:x}, {2,16:x}, {3,6:x}, {4,8:x}", info.Object.ToInt64(), info.UniqueProcessId.ToInt64(), info.HandleValue.ToInt64(), info.GrantedAccess, info.HandleAttributes);
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
  }
```

Output:

```
x32

sizeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX): 28
status: c0000004, return len: 1850052
status: 0, return len: 1850052

           10219,                0,          6729b30,      4,   1fffff
               0,                0,             dfa0,      4,    2001f
               0,                0,             8eb0,      4,    f000f
               0,                0,             fca0,      4,        0
               0,                0,            225b0,      4,    20019
               0,                0,            98210,      4,    f003f
               0,                0,          6758e60,      4,   1f0001
               0,                0,            98040,      4,    2001f
               0,                0,          67534e0,      4,   1f0001
               0,                0,            9c560,      4,    2001f
               0,                0,          6834620,      4,   1fffff
               0,                0,            99250,      4,    f003f
               0,                0,            9a7c0,      4,    f003f
               0,                0,            95380,      4,    f003f
               0,                0,            62d80,      4,    f003f
               0,                0,           15e580,      4,    20019
               0,                0,          6f3b940,      4,       2a
               0,                0,           20da30,      4,        e
               0,                0,           7b07a0,      4,       10
               0,                0,          9af83a0,      4,    20019

x64

sizeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX): 40
status: c0000004, return len: 2647576
status: 0, return len: 2647856

           10294,                0, fffffa8006729b30,      4,        4
   70000001fffff,                0, fffff8a00000dfa0,      4,        8
  2300000002001f,                0, fffff8a000008eb0,      4,        c
   30000000f000f,                0, fffff8a00000fca0,      4,       10
  23000000000000,                0, fffff8a0000225b0,      4,       14
  23000000020019,                0, fffff8a000098210,      4,       18
  230000000f003f,                0, fffffa8006758e60,      4,       1c
  240000001f0001,                0, fffff8a000098040,      4,       20
  2300000002001f,                0, fffffa80067534e0,      4,       24
  240000001f0001,                0, fffff8a00009c560,      4,       28
  2300000002001f,                0, fffffa8006834620,      4,       2c
   80000001fffff,                0, fffff8a000099250,      4,       30
  230000000f003f,                0, fffff8a00009a7c0,      4,       34
  230000000f003f,                0, fffff8a000095380,      4,       38
  230000000f003f,                0, fffff8a000062d80,      4,       3c
  230000000f003f,                0, fffff8a00015e580,      4,       40
  23000000020019,                0, fffffa8006f3b940,      4,       44
   700000000002a,                0, fffff8a00020da30,      4,       48
   500000000000e,                0, fffff8a0007b07a0,      4,       4c
  23000000000010,                0, fffff8a009af83a0,      4,       50
```

Comment: That's simply excellent. I was asking about a generally better approach to dealing with bitness, but receive answers to my more specific question. I wasn't aware of the extended version, thanks!