# P/Invoke 32 bit version of a function

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am writing code in C# that employs P/Invoke functions such as `NtQuerySystemInformation`. However, I notice that this function only returns information pertaining to processes of the same bitness as mine, and I want to get this information from every process on the system. Is there a way that I can invoke both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the function, found in ntdll.dll, from the same method?

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
private static extern NTStatus NtQueryObject(
    IntPtr objectHandle,
    ObjectInformationClass informationClass,
    IntPtr informationPtr,
    uint informationLength,
    ref uint returnLength);
```

Comment: The most obvious way to get ahead is to remove the jitter forcing, there is just no benefit in running in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit OS if you want to do this sort of thing.  Right-click your project > Properties > Build tab > untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  Do keep in mind that NtQuerySystemInformation is already used in the .NET Framework, it provides data for the Process class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preferred approach for conditional compilation for 32-bit versus 64-bit versions of types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992585/preferred-approach-for-conditional-compilation-for-32-bit-versus-64-bit-versions)